# How to use tags like facebook tags FBML, xml schema and javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, schema

how to access elements XML Schema like:

```
<fb:nnnnnnn>
```

with javascript. This is used in buttons of the facebook with FBML..

thanks

Comment: This question desperately needs a rewrite, or it will probably be closed.  Can you find someone that can rewrite this a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementmethods.shtml

```
getElementsByTagNameNS(namespace, localname)
```

Returns as an array all the child elements of the current element with the given local name and namespace.